# How to solve infinite possible coin problem?

Tags: probability

I would need some help with this question:

You toss n coins, each showing heads with probability p, independently
of the other tosses. Each coin that shows tails is tossed again. Let X be the
total number of heads. What is the probability distribution?

The way I tried to solve it is by assuming I am interested in getting 2 heads. In my opinion that would express itself then to:
\begin{equation}
P(X=2) = \binom{\infty}{2} p^2 (1-p)^{\infty - 2}
\end{equation}
The reason I chose infinity as the number of trials is because there is a chance I will never get two heads. But this seems not to be the way to solve this. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The limit of a Binomal distribution is the normal distribution. So the conclusion of the story is - take the limits carefully.

Comment: Here is my understanding of the problem: you have $B_1$ which is Binomial($n$,$p$) and $B_2$ which is, conditional on $B_1$, Binomial($n-B_1$,$p$) and otherwise independent of $B_1$. Then you add them. So you can compute the joint distribution of $B_1$ and $B_2$; given that you can calculate the distribution of $B_1+B_2$. Am I misunderstanding the question? I don't see where the "infinite number of coins" or even "infinite number of tosses" comes into the picture.

Comment: sorry, I dont get it. What is $B_1$ and $B_2$? Like when I look into the answer, they somehow manage to go around the infinity problem... it never appears in their working!

Comment: In what I wrote $B_1$ is the number of heads in the first set of tosses and $B_2$ is the number of heads in the second set of tosses.

Comment: But arent there infinite tosses?

Comment: If there are then I don't think you've communicated that very clearly. To me it sounds like they just flip them all, then they take the tails and flip them again, then they count the number of heads after doing that. That is, just two steps.

Comment: Well it says that if tails appears, the trial is repeated: "throw again." This is as it appears in the book

Comment: I dunno, it's your question; I'm just not seeing any ongoing recursion in what you've said. All I see is two sets of flips: the ones that were tails in the first set of flips get flipped again. Incidentally, if you continue forever, then all of them will be heads eventually.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  The way I read this, each coin can only come out one of three ways:  $H,TH,TT$.  Thus, the probability of getting an $H$ (either in one toss or two) is $q=p+(1-p)p$.  So this is just a binomial process with probability $q$.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: "Each coin that shows tails [after the first toss] is tossed again [once]."

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but unanswered, so this is for those who may be looking for an answer.

The way the event is defined in the question may lead to wrong interpretations.

• **Your interpretation of the event is** : You toss the *n* coins infinitely many times until all coins show heads.

• **The actual event is** : You toss the *n* coins. The coins that show tail are thrown again. Then, the heads are counted. It is not suggested that you repeat the process infinitely many times, you just do this once.

This results in three possible events given by *Ω*={TT,TH,H}, as shown in [this event tree diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeGDz.jpg). The subset of successful events is *S*={TH,H} as the success event is defined by head. The probability of success therefore is *P(S)=p+(1-p)p*.
The probability of failure is *1-P(S)*. Clearly, the number of final heads follows the Binomial distribution Bin(*n,p+(1-p)p*).

Answer (score 0):

Assume each coin is tossed twice and counts as a success if and only if it turns up heads on at least one of the tosses. So $p=\frac{3}{4}$, and the distribution is binomial, with mean $np=\frac{3}{4}n$ and variance $np(1-p)=\frac{3}{16}n$.